# How do you run multiple instances of the same program to simulate multiple clients in eclipse?(Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, server

I used the code from this [link](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/448361/multithreaded-simple-clientserver-chat-console-program). It's a simple java client-server chat program. I want to simulate multiple clients connecting to the server in eclipse. So I ran the server, then I ran a client(which successfully connected) but when I try to run additional clients, they say they are connected but the server does not react (i.e. it should say something like *Recieved connection from /127.0.0.1 on port 58864*).

The weird thing is, I've ran this before and I didn't have any problem then; each client would connect on different port and could communicate with each other. I just don't remember what I did to successfully run multiple clients. In any case, I know the code works but how do you run multiple instances of the same program to simulate multiple clients in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot that I edited the code the first time... Basically the try statement of the server was in a while loop to allow multiple connections. Wasted a good 2 hours on this; sad...